# Логические выражения в Python - ответы на задачи учебника

Tags: python

В учебнике на многие задачи с логическими выражениями дается похожий ответ в форме оператора IF:

```
    sum = 0
    if e == d:
      sum += 1
    if d == s:
      sum += 1
    if s == e:
      sum += 1

    v = sum == 0
    print(v)
```

Но почему не так:

```
 v = (e != d) and (d != s) and (s != a)
 print(v)
```

Или это про любителей разного вкуса и цвета?

Comment: вариантов существует много. Можно и так: `v = not (e == d == s)` ;) PS никогда не используйте в качестве имен собственных переменных/функций/объектов зарезервированные слова, такие как `sum`! После `sum = 0` вы уже не сможете воспользоваться встроенной функцией `sum()`

Comment: такакя штука в тестировании есть. весь тест провалился и можно проверить какие мелкие тесты/сколько тестов провалилось. #одна большая формула неудобно.

Comment: `v = (e != d != s != e)`

Answer (score 0):

Ваша программа и программа учебника выполняет немного разные задачи.

> sum = 0
> if e == d:
> sum += 1
> if d == s:
> sum += 1
> if s == e:
> sum += 1
> v = sum == 0
> print(v)

Сравнивает 3 значения: e; d; s

> v = (e != d) and (d != s) and (s != a)
> print(v)

Сравнивает 4 значения: e; d; s; a
Если это опустить, то можно эту задачу решить можно многими способами.